# Qual è il senso di "arrangiare" in questo passaggio?

Tags: word-meaning

Nella commedia *Sotto paga! Non si paga!* di Dario Fo (testo aggiornato nel 2007 e pubblicato da Einaudi) ho letto:

> Lo capisco
>   da solo come stanno andando davvero le cose: che la politica dei vari governi che si sono succeduti in questi ultimi anni assomiglia sempre di più a un gioco di prestigio
>   da circo coi trucchi tutti scoperti... E dire che io in questo governo, che è appena crollato, ci credevo, e devo ammettere che qualche legge giusta l’ha pure sfornata, come quella, seppur un po’ **arrangiata**, del contratto di noi metalmeccanici...

Ho cercato alle voci "arrangiare" e "arrangiato" del [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI01/00000690.jpg) e del [*vocabolario Treccani*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/arrangiare). Tuttavia, non riesco a capire cosa vuol dire questo personaggio quando afferma che la legge del contratto dei metalmeccanici era "un po’ arrangiata". Me lo sapreste spiegare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La risposta si trova nel link al vocabolario Treccani che hai inserito: significa "messa insieme alla meglio" ovvero imperfetta, raffazzonata. (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/raffazzonare/)

Comment: Quindi, fatta in fretta e senza molta cura?

Comment: Sì, secondo me è corretto 